# trying to create data service in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am attempting to create a new Data Service in WSO2 Data Services Server to connect with SQL Server 2016. However, every time I test the connection it says could not connect database jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.12:1433;Employees with username sa

Comment: Can you specify the error trace in the server terminal? Also, make sure that you have added the db driver to <DSS_HOME>/repository/components/lib and restarted the server.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Exposing+an+RDBMS+as+a+Data+Service

Answer (score 1):

Adding 1433 port in the Sql connective manager has solved my problem

[Add 1433 in all the places where TCP port is written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTj13.png)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without more information. What exception/stack trace you get?

For me this worked without any problem. My jdbc string looks like
 `jdbc:sqlserver://hostname:port;database=databaseName (driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbs.SQLServerDriver)`. 
Can you check if this works for you? I assume you´ve put the jar in the lib folder.

It also might be a network issue. Have you tried to telnet to 10.0.0.12 on port 1433?